# How to define what GruntJS serves?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, gruntjs, yeoman

I am following along on the new Google Developers video [Automating Your Front-End Workflow With Yeoman 1.0](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUQ1fvdO9GY) and things don't really work like it does for Addy.

When I run `grunt server` grunt opens up `/mytodo/dist/index.html` at `http://localhost:9000/`. Why doesn't it load `/mytodo/dist/views/main.html` or `/mytodo/app/views/main.html` like it does for Addy?

Here is my `/mytodo/Gruntfile.js` code:

```
'use strict';
var lrSnippet = require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet;
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
  return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  // load all grunt tasks
  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  // configurable paths
  var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  try {
    yeomanConfig.app = require('./component.json').appPath || yeomanConfig.app;
  } catch (e) {}

  grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,
    watch: {
      coffee: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:dist']
      },
      coffeeTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:test']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass']
      },
      livereload: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ],
        tasks: ['livereload']
      }
    },
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              lrSnippet,
              mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
              mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
              mountFolder(connect, 'test')
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      server: {
        url: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    },
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },
    coffee: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
          src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/scripts',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/spec',
          src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/spec',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    },
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components',
        relativeAssets: true
      },
      dist: {},
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },
    concat: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
            '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      }
    },
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      }
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
          //collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          useShortDoctype: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true*/
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'components/**/*',
            'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
            'styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.renameTask('regarde', 'watch');

  grunt.registerTask('server', [
    'clean:server',
    'coffee:dist',
    'compass:server',
    'livereload-start',
    'connect:livereload',
    'open',
    'watch'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'coffee',
    'compass',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'jshint',
    'test',
    'coffee',
    'compass:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'imagemin',
    'cssmin',
    'htmlmin',
    'concat',
    'copy',
    'cdnify',
    'ngmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);
};
```

Comment: How it works is main.html is included as a partial via ng-view directive of angularjs so when he runs grunt server it opens localhost:9000 which results in index.html being loaded which loads the main.html view inside ng-view directive.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console or in the terminal?  Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I watched the video as well and followed the steps, but for some reason things didn't work out like they did in his video.  I put up a post describing what I had to do to get it running (http://dabwcode.blogspot.com/2013/05/creating-angular-app-with-yeoman-bower.html)

Basically there were 2 things, Yeoman didn't install all the components needed.  In fact Yeoman set up the scaffolding and app/controller, but didn't even install the angular components needed.  So I had to use Bower to install those components independently.

Second, I am on Windows and do not have Ruby anymore on my machine, so Grunt would throw an error when it tried to use the Compass package.  So, that was the second problem.  Removing that in the Gruntfile fixed it all.

Comment: Ok I am on Ubuntu. Did not have issues with Ruby/Compass but your article did help. I had to add `npm install -g bower` and then `bower install angular` to get it working. A post in the yeoman-dev group mentions this issue and Addy responded by adding caption instructions for older versions of yeoman. It turns out in his video that he is using a brand new development version that is about to be released. So its all cleared up now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - it didn't load partial `.html` files and I couldn't use E2E testing.

I solved it using [`$templateCache`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache) or [GruntJS addon for it](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates), if you want it to use Grunt.

That's probably not the best way to solve it and most likely you can configure it properly without `$templateCache`.